# UITabBar(Controller) - Get index of tapped?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I've got a tab bar application and I need to know when and what button a user taps on the tab bar as to display the appropriate notifications and such.

In short: **How would I go about detecting the index of a tapped UITabBarItem on a UITabBar?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, consider this question as an answer:-)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521951/how-to-get-the-tag-of-selected-uitabbaritem-in-uitabbarcontroller-for-more-than

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The answer depends on whether or not the UITabBar is managed by a UITabBarController or not.

**Case 1 - UITabBar is already handled by a UITabBarController**

Implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol.  Specifically the `tabBarContoller:didSelectViewController:` method. Set an instance of your class that implements the protocol as the `delegate` of the `UITabBarController`.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)theTabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSUInteger indexOfTab = [theTabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    NSLog(@"Tab index = %u (%u)", (int)indexOfTab);
}
```

In this case you have to be aware of the special situation where you have enough controllers in the tab controller to cause the "More" tab to be displayed. In that case you'll receive a call to the `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` with a view controller that isn't in the list (it's an instance of an internal UIKit class UIMoreNavigationController). In that case the `indexOfTab` in my sample will be `NSNotFound`.

**Case 2 - UITabBar is NOT already handled by a UITabBarController**

Implement the `UITabBarDelegate` protocol.  Specifically the `tabBar:didSelectItem:` method. Set an instance of your class that implements the protocol as the `delegate` of the `UITabBar`.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)theTabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    NSUInteger indexOfTab = [[theTabBar items] indexOfObject:item];
    NSLog(@"Tab index = %u", (int)indexOfTab);
}
```

EDIT: Modified the method parameter variables to eliminate the OP's compilation warning about `tabBarController` being hidden.

Comment: Sorry but how do you figure out which case you are?

Answer (score 14):

SWIFT:

```
// somewhere inside your TabBarViewController
//...
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    let indexOfTab = tabBar.items?.index(of: item)
    print("pressed tabBar: \(String(describing: indexOfTab))")
}
```

Answer (score 13):

**SWIFT 4:**

I prefer

```
// somewhere inside your TabBarViewController
//...
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, 
                  shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool{
    let index = tabBarController.viewControllers?.index(of: viewController)
    return true// you decide
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There's a method defined in the `UITabBarDelegate` protocol called `tabBar:didSelectItem:`, which will notify you of which and when a `UITabBarItem` is selected (tapped).

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this :
This is in a custom class which extends UITabBarController

.h

```
@interface CustomTabBarController : UITabBarController<UITabBarDelegate>
```

.m

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)theTabBar didSelectItem:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"Tab index = %@ ", theTabBar.selectedItem);
    for(int i = 0; i < theTabBar.items.count; i++)
    {
        if(theTabBar.selectedItem == theTabBar.items[i])
        {
            NSLog(@"%d",i);// this will give the selected tab
        }

    }
    //NSlog(@"Items = %@", theTabBar.items[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple extension for **Swift 4**:

```
extension UITabBarController {
    func getSelectedTabIndex() -> Int? {
        if let selectedItem = self.tabBar.selectedItem {
            return self.tabBar.items?.firstIndex(of: selectedItem)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
let index = getSelectedTabIndex()
```