# Get selected tab in appdelegate

Tags: ios5, xcode4

I want to get a code, that I want the selected tab index in appdelegate. I can get this in my view controller, but how can I get this in my appdelegate?

Can anybody help me out doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITabBar(Controller) - Get index of tapped?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766230/uitabbarcontroller-get-index-of-tapped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use MyTabBar.selectedIndex  and put in Object in AppDelegateClass..
Or if you have already TabBar Avaliable
you can use

```
AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"%i",app.Tab.selectedIndex);
```

if you need to get it in the same calss so you can use

```
NSLog(@"%i",self.Tab.selectedIndex);
```

if you want to prevent user from going to another tab you can use delegate

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 3) {
            //if the user will select tab  3 so user will not go to it 
        return NO;
    }else{
            // if any other tab so return yse will let you to other tabs
        return YES;
    }

}
```

Comment: In the class that you want to get the selected tab in it.. just import your applicationdelegate class and use this code to access selected tabbar

Comment: But, buddy, is it possible, if I want to get it in the appdelegate class? Cause actually want user to prevent vising a view controller with respect to some condition.

Comment: @SoumalyaBanerjee - i have linked a question above, you can check that.

Comment: I have edited my answer so you can prevent user from switching tabs based on condition..